# Nikon D500 + Tamron 18-400 or Sony RX100 m6

Tags: nikon, image-quality, tamron, sony-rx100

I would like to buy a lens for my Nikon D500 or maybe another small camera just for travelling. I looked for Tamron 18-400 lens and Sony RX100m6, but I can't decide. As I saw, Sony has the advantages that is very small and lighter compared with my Nikon D500. What I'm afraid, is regarding the photos quality and I will need to change/charge the batteries very often. I started to look for Tamron 18-400 which I saw that is weather sealed compared with Sony which is not. What you would recommend me between these 2 options? Thank you.

Comment: Look at what you're in need of, is weight at issue? will you be doing photography in the rain? are you concerned over battery usage? - answer these questions and you'll find your answer.

Comment: It's also worth noting that "superzoom" lenses such as the 18-400 are generally regarded as poor performers. There are too many trade-offs in designing such a lens. "Jack of all trades, master of none"

Comment: @osullic Jack of all trades, *master of one*. Those superzooms make damn good paper weights.

Comment: Andrei, when I went to Iceland, I brought my entire kit: FF camera, tripod, 16-35, 85, 70-200, 100mm filter kit..because I wanted to get awesome shots of the aurora, waterfalls, sunsets, etc. When I went on cruise, I took an Olympus Tough. Very, very different scenarios and needs. Saying "travel photos" really doesn't provide any information for the type of shooting you want to do while away. Please provide much, much more info about the types of photos you want to get and what your constraints are.

Comment: Super zoom lenses are way better than some years ago. Many opinions about super zooms are still based on the poor performance of the early lenses of this kind. I saw a newer one and the quality is way better than some normal zoom lenses of 20+ years ago. sure they are not as good as new primes and big standard zooms, but still not just paper weights. Espacially for traveling a light always on lens is a very good thing. Sure not the best but still not crap af.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Super zoom vs. moderate zoom in compacts](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/27059/super-zoom-vs-moderate-zoom-in-compacts)

Comment: @Hueco I want to go to Scandinavia in the summer. I will travel a lot with the bus and I will not have so much time to change the lenses or to mount the tripod because will be an organised trip with guide. For this I didn't want to take so many lenses with me. For landscape now, I really love my Tokina 11-16, but I wanted a lens to have quite good quality to not be necessary to change it very often. I have also the lens kit 18-105 but is quite soft at least on the margins. This Tamron looked nice for what it offers, but I see RX100 more portable. I would like maybe to print images on A3.Thanks

Comment: @xiota thanks, but I wanted to hear opinions also from users who have one of these combinations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I really love my Tokina 11-16

Rule #1 to being happy on location: Don't leave the lens you love at home.

I'm very much surprised with this perception of <'caveman voice'>urgh. change lens bad. you miss shot<'/caveman'>. You have an *interchangeable* lens camera because you've recognized that purpose built lenses perform better than do-everything lenses.

I mentioned in the comments my last trip. Here's how it broke down:

- 16-35 f/4 + 100mm filter kit: Landscapes, cityscapes, general touristy shots
- 85 f/1.2: portraits, aurora, telephoto touristy, anything at night
- 70-200 f/4: daytime touristy, hiking/wildlife (this trip really wasn't about the wildlife, else I would have brought a 400)

The 16-35 lived on my camera *most* of the time followed by the cannonball. I didn't miss a shot because of a lens change. This is a fear that people have that I've found is rarely justified. You're not shooting a wedding - you're traveling. Take your time. (Or, use a hip/messenger bag for lens swaps. Don't worry about caps, your lens is tougher than you think. Detach, toss in bag, grab, attach, shoot.)

Also - I too did some bus tours on this trip. It wasn't an issue even setting up a tripod and taking ~5min exposures. Get to know your bus driver (I found out mine was a photographer on the side) - they do have a schedule to keep but they're human too and will give you an extra moment or two if you need it.

---

Yea, I know I didn't answer your question. It's because I disagree with the fundamental premise. If you really want a superzoom or a bridge over maximizing your photographic opportunity, then more power to you. But, I can tell you that personally, there's no way I could have walked away from Iceland satisfied had I only brought a superzoom. But, to each their own.